# expected 0 arguments, but got 1 while passing arguments to the createAsyncThunk function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

This is my service in which i'm calling api(with arguments)

```
    const battle = async (obj:any): Promise<result[]> =>{
    const data=await fetch(`${API_URL}`,{
    method: "POST",
  
    // Adding body or contents to send
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "1stArg": obj.arg1,
      "2ndArg": obj.arg2
    }),
      
    // Adding headers to the request
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
  });
   const res = await data.json()
   return res;
}
```

This is my action in which I'm calling that service

```
export const getResult=createAsyncThunk<result[]>(
  'testing/getResult',
  async(obj:any)=>{
    const data= await services.battle(obj);
    return data;
  }
);
```

This is the reducer

```
  builder.addCase(getResult.pending, (state) => ({
    ...state,
    result: null,
  }));

  builder.addCase(getResult.rejected, (state) => ({
    ...state,
    result: null,
  }));

  builder.addCase(getResult.fulfilled, (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    result: action.payload,
  }));
```

Selector

```
export const getFinalResult = (state: RootState) => state.monsters.result;
```

This is how I'm using

```
const result=useSelector(getFinalResult);
const handleStartBattleClick = () => {
    let obj={
        fistArg,2ndArg
    }
    dispatch(getResult(obj))
}
```

and getting this error

> Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify that generic up there, you have to do so fully:

```js
export const getResult=createAsyncThunk<ResultType, ArgumentType>(
```

otherwise it will fall back to `void`, which means "no argument".

Comment: If you want the thunk to take an argument, and you are putting `<>` (generic arguments) behind `createAsyncThunk`, you have to pass the type of the argument you want your thunk to have as the second argument in those `<>`.
Or skip the generic arguments completely. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk